# Want to get the response of nested api call and then send back to my middle ware node js api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, async-await

I want to use async await in the nested api call but not figure out how ? So the response of 2nd api send back to \api\sign_in response which i get from front end is there any solution here is my code:
....

```
app.post("/api/sign_in", (req, res) => {

          console.log("i am in login call");
          const resp = scaryClown(req.body.email, req.body.password);
          console.log("here you should wait for above response and then pass 
             this  response  into /api/sign_in response");
               res.send(resp);
 });

function scaryClown(email, password) {
request.post(
  key.sign_in_url,
  {
    json: {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      email = response.headers.uid;

      key.email = response.headers.uid;
      key.client = response.headers.client;
      var result = [];
      for (var i in response.headers) result.push(i, response.headers[i]);
      access_token = result[17];
      key.access_token = access_token;
      key.expiry = response.headers.expiry;

      apiresponse = response.body;
      console.log("apiresponse");
      console.log(apiresponse);
      return apiresponse;
    }

    console.log("==============");
    console.log(response.body);
    return response.body;
  }
);
}
```

....

Comment: To use async/await you need version of request library that returns promises. There are suggestions in the request library docs. Otherwise add a callback argument to `scaryClown()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait for the response of your scaryClown function you can use await before
your function call.

```
app.post("/api/sign_in", async (req, res) => {

    console.log("i am in login call");
    const resp = await scaryClown(req.body.email, req.body.password);
    console.log("here you should wait for above response and then pass 
          this  response  into / api / sign_in response");
            res.send(resp);
});

function scaryClown(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(
        key.sign_in_url,
        {
            json: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                email = response.headers.uid;

                key.email = response.headers.uid;
                key.client = response.headers.client;
                var result = [];
                for (var i in response.headers) result.push(i, response.headers[i]);
                access_token = result[17];
                key.access_token = access_token;
                key.expiry = response.headers.expiry;

                apiresponse = response.body;
                console.log("apiresponse");
                console.log(apiresponse);
                resolve(apiresponse);
            }

            console.log("==============");
            console.log(response.body);
            resolve(response.body);
        }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: i already try this approach but this not work as in node i get the empty response i want to get the response of my scary clown then this response pass to the sign_in api

Comment: ok in that case you can return a promise from your scaryClown function. it should work. i have edited the code in my response.